# How to configure Angular JS with Liferay?

Tags: angularjs, liferay, liferay-6

I am trying to configure Angular JS with Liferay, Can anybody tell me how can i configure angular js with liferay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a good startup point: [portlet](https://github.com/sammso/poc-angular-portlet) , [tutorial](https://www.liferay.com/fr/web/sampsa.sohlman/blog/-/blogs/trying-the-angularjs-with-liferay)

I tested it before and it works well on `Liferay-6.2.2`.

And don't forget to add this property to `portal-ext.properties`:

```
minifier.enabled=false
```

**EDIT**

You can add `angluar.js` to your `portal-normal.vm` if you want to include it on your theme (so you won't have to add it on each portlet) this way :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$javascript_folder/angular.js"
    charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Another way to include angular js library to `liferay` portlets by simply adding it to the `liferay-portlet.xml` this way:

```
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/angular.min.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/angular-portlet.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/main.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
```

if you have a logic to apply on the theme i would recommend that you use it within an embedded portlet and then register it using the `angular-portlet.js`

Comment: do we have to add this property in portal_normal.vm file? `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${javascript_folder}/my.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

Comment: okay thats fine, but what if i want to use it in my themes? 
how can i configure that?

Comment: @Akash you can include the angular-js min and by doing that you won't have to add it in each portlet. But may i suggest that if you have other intentions other then that, the best way to achieve it is within an embedded-portlet within your theme.

Comment: Thanks that exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: how can i mark it as answer, your comment is not even in Answerbox

Comment: @Akash my answer is within the answer box now :)